# Debounce switches on car stereo bluetooth receiver

Tags: bluetooth, debounce

I have retrofitted a Bluetooth receiver to an old car stereo, replacing the cassette. Although this generally works fine, there has been some issues with the three play-pause/ff/rw momentary switches I put on the front of the stereo. The BT receiver unit did not come with solder pads for these switches, but I'd found online instructions to solder wires to several PIO pins to make this work, which it does.

The BT receiver unit is a blue CSR A64215 pcb unit which is attached to a larger controller board (see pic of similar unit).

[image: this is a similar BT unit]

The BT unit has been in the car for over a year, and it's worked, though *sometimes* these front-mounted p-p/ff/rw switches stop working, usually after the car has been driven for a 15-20 mins - almost like it's overheating but it's def not overheating. The BT audio signal itself doesn't stop working, and you can change music tracks from the phone outputting the BT signal, but it's just these front-mounted buttons that can stop responding.

I am wondering about the possibility of switch bounce - eg - when driving along, the existing switch bounce is exacerbated by vibrations from the car in motion, meaning the BT receiver is getting triggered so many times when a button is pressed, it stops responding correctly.

At the moment, I have wired these with a 1K resistor between the three PIO pins, and the 1.8v pin they get triggered by (see diagram). I can't remember the online source that suggested putting the 1k res in, but since then I have seen similar BT units using 86K or other larger resistors inserted - so I'm not sure what would be the best res size to use.

[image: diagram of the switch wiring as it is]

I am currently thinking about whether to put in simple debounce circuits on these pressure switches, eg a res and cap - to pre-emptively minimise this. But being a noob, I can't use a scope to observe the switch bounce, and anyway, a bench-test wouldn't reproduce the conditions of the vibrations within the moving car. So - I'd have to use cap and resistor values that were general best-guess should-do-the-job sizes.

Firstly - is switch bounce a possible issue here? I can't see any problems with poor connections and the BT unit is not getting hot.
If so - or either way - would it be a reasonable precaution to put simple debounce circuits on those switches - eg - res and cap - to pre-emptively minimise switch bounce?

Thanks in advance for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think switch bounce caused by ambient vibrations is the issue here. Switches and resistors are typically not as microphonic as e.g. ceramic capacitors. Unless your buttons register multiple presses when you press them once, debouncing is probably not the answer.

Does your PIOs have internal pull-downs? According to [this datasheet](https://www.tinyosshop.com/datasheet/CSRA64215%20QFN%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) that I found, they are described as "Bidirectional with strong
pull-up". If that is the case for your unit, I don't quite understand how it works at all when your 1kΩ resistor is connected to 1.8V and not GND.

I would probably try to delete the 1kΩ resistor, and connect the switches to GND instead of 1.8V, unless there's something in the documentation that advises against it.

By the way, how long are your wires? There can be a fair bit of EMI in cars. Maybe also consider shielding or twisted pairs if the wires are more than a few centimeters long.